# How to change the "owner" of a Facebook account

Tags: facebook

I am a member of a club, that has a Facebook account that was opened by the previous secretary.  She has since left and we can't get in touch with her, hence are locked out of this account

Is there any way we could change the "owner" or cancel the account completely and start a new one?

One of our officials has started a new accounts already, but that just creates confusion, if anyone is looking for this account by the club's name (we now ended up having several)

We would like to delete them all, except for one.

BTW, have another, related, question.

So that this can't reoccur, is there a way of opening a Facebook account without ONE individual being the "owner"?

Comment: Is the account a profile (that other people can add as a friend) or a page (that people can like and share)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change owner of a Facebook account until owner has provided you email and password (or you have managed to get it from somewhere).

If it is a Facebook Page you can change the Admin or select more than one Admin if you are an Admin of that page.

As you have mentioned in the question she (owner) has left and you can't get in touch with her... so you don't have any option here to do anything with that account. It will always with her only.

Now, you can create a new Facebook account (better [create a Page](https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/set-up-facebook-page) for the club instead of account), and report to the Facebook about the existing page, tell them in details and request to take it down.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Facebook's terms of use](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms), making a profile for something other than a yourself is not allowed:

> #### Registration and Account Security
>
> Facebook users provide their real names and information, and we need
> your help to keep it that way. Here are some commitments you make to
> us relating to registering and maintaining the security of your
> account:
>
> 1. You will not provide any false personal information on
>    Facebook, or create an account for anyone other than yourself without
>    permission.
> 2. You will not create more than one personal account.
> 3. You will not use your personal timeline primarily for your
>    own commercial gain, and will use a Facebook Page for such purposes.
> 4. You will not share your
>    password (or in the case of developers, your secret key), let anyone
>    else access your account, or do anything else that might jeopardize
>    the security of your account.

In order to shut that profile down, you should first [set up a page for your club](https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/set-up-facebook-page). Pages can have several administrators and retain most features you'd like: chat, albums, ability to share and interact with other accounts (including profiles), etc. [If you register your page as Local Business, Company, or Organization, you can apply for verification](https://www.facebook.com/help/100168986860974?helpref=related&ref=related), which is another layer of security to prevent further issues in the future.

After that, report every account you find for [impersonation](https://www.facebook.com/help/167722253287296?helpref=related). Facebook will ask for proof of identification and, after a few days, will remove all of them.